# How do you exit a game when you hit an enemy?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a game where you are going to dodge the enemies. I want to implement a feature where the game exits when the player hits an enemy. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the required code for [Terminating a Java Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452930/terminating-a-java-program), placed to run from your [hit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing)/[collision detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection).

Comment: @Gnemlock should the title be written as a normal sentence?

Comment: @Archmede, as long as it makes sense. A question is favorable.

Answer (score 1):

If by exit you mean terminate the program then the Java way is to simply call

```
System.exit(0);
```

when the player hits an enemy or call a shutdown method within your program.

If by exit you mean go to a main menu screen then I would recommend that you have a game state system so that when the player hits an enemy, the current state is switched to the main menu state which is updated and rendered. This would also mean that the you would have another state for the actual gameplay which then allows you to easily switch between the two.

For example:

```
//Player class
public void onHit() {
    State.setState(State.mainMenuState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you hit your enemy, which should be captured by any event, or whatever, call `System.exit(0);` in Java.

Wherever you have your enemy hit detection method/function, you could call `System.exit(0);`, thereby exiting the application on hitting the enemy.

However, it's a common approach to return to a menu after the game is over, so I suggest you try that too, if you wish to.

Hope this helps you!!

Abhigyan Chattopadhyay.

Answer (score -1):

I should ask in advance, do you want the actual game itself to close? Or do you want the game to simply go back to the main menu.

If its the former, System.Exit(0) works just fine. Your game will close and the JVM will handle the rest. If however you want it to go to the main menu, I'd just create a small function which resets the games state and displays the main menu screen.

Hope this helped!